# How to cancel a zle function after triggering the bindkey?

Tags: zsh, zle, fzf

Hope you're doing well.

I have the following in my `.zshrc`:

```bash
# 1. invoke zoxide to pick dir
# 2. open target dir in ranger
# 3. when exiting ranger, cd into last dir
zoxide_to_ranger () {
    eval 'ranger "$(zoxide query -i)" --choosedir=$HOME/.rangerdir < $TTY'
    LASTDIR=$(< ~/.rangerdir)
    cd "$LASTDIR" || exit

    # ensure `precmds` are run after `cd`
    local precmd
    for precmd in $precmd_functions; do
      $precmd
    done
    zle reset-prompt
}

zle -N zoxide_to_ranger
bindkey '^f' zoxide_to_ranger
```

As suggested in the inline comment, it's a handy tool such that when I trigger `Ctrl-f`, it'll prompt me a fzf menu, and upon selection it'll open ranger in that dir.

The problem is that, when I want to cancel selection by pressing `Esc`, it'll still open up ranger and send me the home dir, which is not what I want.

So my question is, how do I cancel such a zle function after triggering the bindkey?

Config:

zsh 5.9 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

OS: Manjaro Linux

Any input is much appreciated. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eval` line is doing several things. Maybe too many things. One
approach would be to separate out the `zoxide` call, and to check
whether it has returned something. Another need would be to check
whether `~/.rangerdir` has a directory (or something) in it, and to
empty that file after use. These new checks create multiple points
the function must cleanup and exit from:

```
function zoxide_to_ranger {
  local zz; zz=$(zoxide query -i)
  [[ -z $zz ]] && { zle reset-prompt; return }

  # not sure if the 'eval' is necessary; does ranger ever exit with
  # shell commands to be run?
  ranger $zz --choosedir=~/.rangerdir < $TTY

  local dd; dd=$(< ~/.rangerdir)
  [[ -z $dd ]] && { zle reset-prompt; return }
  :> ~/.rangerdir

  # this could be "local" unless you use it elsewhere
  LASTDIR=$dd
  cd $LASTDIR || { zle reset-prompt; return }

  local precmd; for precmd in $precmd_functions; $precmd
  zle reset-prompt
}
```

Comment: Hello @thrig. Thank you so much for helping me out. I really appreciate it. However, I tried both solutions but ended up hanging in the terminal (empty screen with no cursor). I need to press `Esc` again to go back to prompt. I looked into `man zoxide` but couldn't find the exit code. `zoxide query -i` and then a simple `Esc` takes me back to prompt. I suspect it's a `ranger` issue? Any idea?

Comment: Hello @thrig. You just made my day! Thank you again after almost a year later. I see that you've edited your answer and it's exactly what I needed. I've studied how you restructured with multiple checks. Thank you again!

Comment: I've tried the edited solution but found that I need to change from `--choosedir=~/.rangerdir` to `--choosedir=$HOME/.rangerdir` (i.e., you need to change from `~` to `$HOME`) in order for it to work. Cheers!